# Continous integration of a Windows application using Jenkins

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild

I am having a Windows application which was created on VB.Net and Visual Studio 2008, The application is somewhat big and is around 10 years old. The repository we are using is TFS. I am having a task to create an automatic build for this Windows application and I choose the Jenkins CI for it.

My plan is to build the project solution using MS Build plugin and then publish it and deploy the solution to IIS path.

I have given the below MS Build query to build using Jenkins and get the solution code from TFS and the output was successful:

```
/t:AppProcSolution /p:Configuration=Release /maxcpucount
```

But I need publish the same AppProcSolution. Could I do it by passing any other parameters to the above script or should I need to use MS deploy etc. **I am totally new to automatic integration**. Is it possible for me get the published solution to a particular folder? Almost all the .Net integration using Jenkins tutorial available on the Internet is for deployment to GitHub etc. So if someone has any guidelines to help please provide me a solution.

Comment: /t:rebuild /t:AppProcSolution:publish /p:Configuration=Release;PublishDir=C:\AppProcSolution\ 

The above query helped me in publishing the windows application using MSbuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDeploy is good for server application deployments like web applications/sites, SQL server databases or Windows Services.

When you say "Windows application" I assume you mean a WinForm or desktop client application.  The best tool for this, in my opinion, is ClickOnce:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx

You could also use a Setup project in VS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes I need to deploy a Windows form application, I am currently using ClickOnce, But my need is to automate it using jenkins or bamboo, I need to make the release based on JIRA task.

Comment: Automated the commandline tool via jenkins - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx

Comment: @chief7 Hi I want to do it for windows form/desktop app with octopus & jenkins. Can you  pls guide me the jenkins commandline.